# How to use a String Builder in C#

Tags: c#, database

I have a default value, fiscal year and comment code that I need to incorporate in a line item on a database.  At the end of the line item I need to reserve the last four spaces the comment.  My questions are how do I use a string builder to do this.  Should I make the comment a class variable and leave it blank (i.e "")

So far I have the following but am at a lost as to what to do next:

`var fiscalYearPrefix = $"{base.EventContext["vars.FiscalYearPrefix"]} + "2022" + comment"; var sb = new StringBuilder() sb.Append(ToNCharacters(, 20));`

I'm trying to output something like this:
FM202200000000002638
(2638 is the comment)

Comment: As an exercise, using StringBuilder here is fine. For performance, your original "concatenate in single statement" is better. StringBuilder shines when you add to a string(-builder) *using a loop*

Comment: OT your `ToNCharacters`, does that use [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding#padleft)? It's better to first pad your "comment", and *then* add it to the result

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thanks for the clarification! I wasn't sure if I was on the right track and it seems that I am (some what), I am in fact suing the string builder with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(base.EventContext["vars.FiscalYearPrefix"]);
sb.Append("2022");
sb.Append(ToNCharacters(0, 20));
var fiscalYearPrefix = sb.ToString();
```

Or string interpolation for single sentences is OK, although the `sb.AppendLine` method is very handy:

```
var fiscalYearPrefix = $"{base.EventContext["vars.FiscalYearPrefix"]}2022{new String('0', 5)}{comment}";
```